# URL Redirect to sub domain

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I have a subfolder: example.com/forum. I want to force people to forum.example.com. Is that possible and how to do it in the .htaccess file? Also, I want when someone goes to "/forum" a message says "file not found or a 404 message.

Also I would like to prevent: "forum.example.com/forum". Just the "forum." will do.

Thanks for your help.

PS: I have created the sub domain.

Answer (score 0):

This should 301 redirect anyone going to /forum to the forum subdomain:

```
RewriteRule ^/forum/?$     http://forum.example.com [R=301,NC,L]
```

Assuming your subdomain points to subfolder of your example.com site, it will also redirect forum.example.com/forum.

Comment: Thanks for that. That method will work. Can you explain why most website has domain/forum 404 page and not when I go to forum.domain.com?